# Programmatically Submit form and loop through paging (C#.NET)

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I need to write a custom web-scraper to mine some data. ?I know how to submit a form using HttpWebRequest class Post method. My challenge is to loop through the resulting pages and retrieve the records from each page.

Does anyone have a code sample or article to point to? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: great resource! Thanks, am playing with this.